# Creating files based on column values in shell script

Tags: shell

I've big files which each line have five columns. Like this:

```
1234   58493  12334 98034 2344
9873   58493  4535  3453  64435
32453  58493  76546 1344  67867
7456    3457  234   2346  34547
4234    3457  7809  3452  12456
1234    3457  5345  1234  7548
...
```

I'm needing to process this file generating others based on the second column. So, in the example above, I want to generate the following two files.

58493.txt

```
1234   58493  12334 98034 2344
9873   58493  4535  3453  64435
32453  58493  76546 1344  67867
```

and

3457.txt

```
7456    3457  234   2346  34547
4234    3457  7809  3452  12456
1234    3457  5345  1234  7548
```

I'm using this script for this.

```
while read LINE
do
    varible=`echo $LINE | cut -d " " -f 2`
    echo $LINE >> $OUTPUT/$variable.txt
done < $INPUT/file.txt
```

The problem is, this script is infeasible in terms of time.

Do someone know a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say if this will be faster, but you can avoid the subshell, executable invocation (`cut`), variable assignment, and the open-append-close cycle happening for *each line*.  Here is how I might approach the problem, given your description:

```
  # Step 1: get all of the unique identifiers
$ UNIQ_IDS="$(awk '{print $2}' < big_file | sort | uniq)"

  # Step 2: iterate the identifiers, pull out the matching lines
$ for i in $UNIQ_IDS; do
    grep -E "^\\S+ +$i " > $i.txt
  done
```

The downside to this approach over yours is that yours will work on an infinitely large file, as it makes its decisions on the fly.  This approach, however, preprocesses the data first, then iterates over the file N more times.  Consequently, depending on the details of your problem, this may not be a win.

How does this work?  Given your example above:

- `awk '{print $2}' < big_file` prints only the second column of it's input, which in this case, is `big_file`.
- That output gets piped (`|`) to `sort` which does it's namesake, ensuring all like-items are grouped together.
- The sorted output gets piped (`|`) to `uniq` which removes all duplicates from the stream (necessary to sort first; I'll leave why as an exercise in reading the manual page `man sort` and `man uniq`).
- Finally, all that was executed in a "sub-shell" `$( ... )`, and the output is stored in `UNIQ_IDS`.  This variable now holds:

  ```
  $ echo $UNIQ_IDS
  3457 58493
  ```

Part 2, then, might afford a speedup, because it's only writing to each file *once* (rather than opening and closing a file once per line of `big_file`), and makes use of `grep` which is written in C and made for the purpose.  Finally, what is `-E "^\\S+ +$i "`?  That's a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/), in this case, saying to:

- (`^`) - anchor to the beginning of the line,
- (`\S+`) - match the first non-whitespace characters (the first column); note the lack of double backslash here, explained below
- (`+`) - match one or more *space* characters
- (`$i`) - match your exactly loop variable, for example, `3457`,
- () - match a final space, so as to delimit the second column

So, the first iteration of the loop would turn into (effectively):

```
grep -E "^\\S+ +3457 " > 3457.txt
```

And thus, after shell interpretation, the actual regex sent to `grep` is:

```
^\S+_+3457_
```

(Spaces changed to underscore [`_`] for presentation here only.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just changed the line `grep -E "^\\S+ +$i " > $i.txt` for `grep -E "^\\S+ +$i " big_file > $i.txt`. Let's see how much it will be improved.